# Conditional arguments in Views 3

Tags: 7, views

I have created content type ad with 2 fields:

- field1 (select list)
- field2 (select list)

created a block in views with contextual filters:

1. field1 and "provide default argument" > php code:

   $node = node_load(arg(1));
   return $node->field1['und'][0]['value'];
2. field2 and "provide default argument" > php code:

   $node = node_load(arg(1));
   return $node->field2['und'][0]['value'];

When node has all fields chosen, it works well, but if i omit 1st or 2nd field, views hiding my block. If i set "Show all values" if no default argument present, then it shows all nodes.

How can i make contextual fields optional? E.g. if first field has no value then just omit it and use 2nd contextual filter.

Comment: I can't really understand what you're describing. Can you show like a screenshot of your views config?

Comment: I will update my question.